# Variables not set in java code

Tags: java

Please have alook at below code

```
public class Account {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int accountNumber;
    private int apin;
    private double abalance;

    public Account(String fname, String lname, int anumber, int pin,
            double balance) {
        fname = firstName;
        lname = lastName;
        anumber = accountNumber;
        pin = apin;
        balance = abalance;

        System.out.println("variables set");
    }

    public String getfirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getlastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getaccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public int getpin() {
        return apin;
    }

    public double getbalance() {
        return abalance;
    }

}
```

```
public class bank {

    private Account[] account;
    boolean flag = false;
    Account returnAccount;

    public Account bank(int anum, int pin) {
        account = new Account[3];
        account[0] = new Account("Steve", "Kom", 1234, 333, 50000);
        account[1] = new Account("Mack", "Dumbo", 2345, 123, 80000);
        account[2] = new Account("Xina", "Patt", 2145, 222, 40000);

        System.out.println(account[0].getaccountNumber());

        for (Account aa : account) {
            System.out.println(aa.getaccountNumber());
        }

        return returnAccount;
    }
}
```

In above code the get methods always return me 0, why the variables are not getting set.
I am so confused what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Poor question. You didn't bother to point out *which* variables aren't being set. You should attempt to debug your code so you can 1) narrow the scope of your problem down and 2) possibly fix an apparent foo on your part by being forced to further scrutinize the code.

Comment: Your instance variables are not getting set because they are not getting set. Do you see any line where they are getting set?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong assignment syntax in constructor :

```
public Account(String fname, String lname, int anumber, int pin,
        double balance) {
    fname = firstName; //incorrect assignment
    lname = lastName; //incorrect assignment
    anumber = accountNumber; //incorrect assignment
    pin = apin; //incorrect assignment
    balance = abalance; //incorrect assignment

    System.out.println("variables set");
}
```

that should be

```
public Account(String fname, String lname, int anumber, int pin, double balance) {
      firstName = fname; //switched - correct assignment
      lastName = lname ; //switched - correct assignment
      accountNumber = anumber; //switched - correct assignment
      apin = pin ; //switched - correct assignment
      abalance = balance; //switched - correct assignment

      System.out.println("variables set");
}
```

Comment: But he also needs to switch all the other assignments as well.

Comment: @Stendika : updating takes atleast 2 mins...i type slow!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting wrong values in constructor

```
fname = firstName;
```

change it to

```
this.firstName  = fname;
```

Comment: wow dumbest mistake ever.
I have all language mixed up shell, plsql and all
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
public Account(String fname, String lname, int anumber, int pin,
    double balance) {
fname = firstName; // swap
lname = lastName; // swap
anumber = accountNumber; 
pin = apin;
balance = abalance;

System.out.println("variables set");
}
```

Comment: This answer really needs some kind of explanation.